# React-native reload on ubuntu and android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, adb

I'm trying to refresh my app on the emulator, but when I press twice 'R', nothing happens ... the only way I found is to do:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

and click on 'Refresh' ...

Thank you very much